# Unable to run an Asp.Net core application as Windows Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to allow the execution of an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API as Windows Service...
The problem I've is that the application hangs on RunAsService.

Here's the code of my program.cs

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();

            var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                .CreateLogger();

            Log.Logger = logger;
            var app = new CommandLineApplication();



            app.HelpOption();
            var optionHosting = app.Option("--hosting <TYPE>", "Type of the hosting used. Valid options: `service` and `console`, `console` is the default one", CommandOptionType.SingleValue);
            var optionPort = app.Option("--port <NUMBER>", "Post will be used, `5000` is the default one", CommandOptionType.SingleValue);
            app.OnExecute(() =>
            {
                //


                try
                {
                    var hosting = optionHosting.HasValue()
                            ? optionHosting.Value()
                            : "console";

                    var port = optionPort.HasValue()
                        ? new Func<int>(() =>
                        {
                            if (int.TryParse(optionPort.Value(), out var number))
                            {
                                // Returning successfully parsed number
                                return number;
                            }

                            // Returning default port number in case of failure
                            return 5000;
                        })()
                        : 5000;

                    var builder = GetHostBuilder(args, port);

                    if (Debugger.IsAttached || hosting.ToLowerInvariant() != "service")
                    {
                        builder
                            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                            .Build()
                            .Run();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        logger.Information("ci arrivo");
                        var processModule = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
                        logger.Information("ci arrivo2");

                        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(processModule);
                        if (processModule != null)
                            builder
                                .UseContentRoot(processModule)
                                .Build()
                                .RunAsService();

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {

                    logger.Error(exception, "");
                }
            });

            app.Execute(args);

        }
```

And here's the `GetHostBuilder`

```
  public static IWebHostBuilder GetHostBuilder(string[] args, int port) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseUrls($"http://*:{port}")
                .UseStartup<Startup>().UseSerilog();
```

Looking at MSDN [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.windowsservices.webhostwindowsserviceextensions.runasservice?view=aspnetcore-3.0) it tells that

> Runs the specified web application inside a Windows service and blocks until the service is stopped

## UPDATE 1

After doing some debug I've seen that the web api responds, but when I run it as console I got in the log

```
11:25:08 INF] Running as Console application
[11:25:10 DBG] Hosting starting
[11:25:10 DBG] Failed to locate the development https certificate at 'null'.
[11:25:10 DBG] Hosting started
[11:25:10 DBG] Loaded hosting startup assembly xxx
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: C:\xxxx\xxxx
Now listening on: http://[::]:46700
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

When I run as service

```
2020-05-21 11:15:25.748 +02:00 [DBG] Hosting starting
2020-05-21 11:15:25.980 +02:00 [DBG] Failed to locate the development https certificate at 'null'.
2020-05-21 11:15:26.022 +02:00 [DBG] Hosting started
2020-05-21 11:15:26.022 +02:00 [DBG] Loaded hosting startup assembly xxx
```

No information about the hosting port and so on. The other strange thing is that it continues to write under `c:\windows\system32\` even if I set the WorkindDirectory and also the ContentRoot

Comment: In the MSDN link that you have provided, there is an example that says in a comment that "// This call will block until the service is stopped.". It seems that this is intended functionality. You might want to have the command line application running on a separate thread.

Comment: I know but in the sample I've taken (using CommandLineApplication) it does so...was wondering it was the right way of doing that

Comment: I believe the app.OnExecute is the threading you were referring to. From what I can see and understand in the code above is that the app is executed, the app then starts a thread in the OnExecute and then that runs the host as a service and hangs. How about opening up another thread within the OnExecute method and have that run the hose as a service. That way the OnExecute task can close and the command line app can continue.

Comment: In the truth, the service works... but for some reason the output I receive when I run it from console, seems cutted

Comment: What do you mean seems cutted?

Comment: look at my update pls